What's the fastest real-world travel time to the opposite side of the world?
Imagine you are the most important and powerful person on Earth.
One day, you're giving a talk in Managua, Nicaragua, when something important suddenly happens on the opposite side of the planet: Jakarta, Indonesia. Now, you need to take your own personage to Jakarta urgently.
Besides the one fictional detail of you being the dictator of Earth, the setting is real-world current-day Earth.
What is the fastest you can get from Managua to Jakarta?

You use any real travel method that would be realistically available to Earth's supreme political leader.
Yes, we have supersonic fighter jets, but I assume political leaders do not normally travel with fighter jets in tow (esp. during peacetime), so you must take into account whatever delay is needed to scramble the necessary resources. Suppose you have the standard kind of entourage that a President has during peacetime.

You are an absolute dictator with unqualified right-of-way.
The full machinery of the state everywhere on Earth will make this happen. Pilots and other personnel will literally come running to respond. You do not need to make excuses to anybody to cancel your talk and leave unceremoniously. All air-space is your air-space, all property is your property, you are the law.

It is urgent that you get there as fast as possible.
You will pull out all the stops. The unspecified event in Jakarta is a bad thing that you're rushing to fix, so your heels will be lightened by the urgency of fear.

You are a regular fleshy human and desk-ish bureaucrat.
You are not a SEAL who is trained in HALO jumps. You have no special ability to withstand high-G or other strenuous travel. Let's even give you a serious head-cold right now. Everybody else will be running, but you will be limited to a brisk walk.

The weather is good



I'm tagging this hard-science:
Outside the frame of science-fiction and physics, I imagine that calls for a detailed itinerary that enumerates every leg of the journey, what kind of transportation will be used for each leg (exact make and model of vehicles), accounting for stuff like how each vehicle will be obtained (like, where are they kept, how long it takes to scramble them to their rendezvous points), how far each can travel without refueling and what can be done to expedite or avoid refueling stops, how long each leg is expected take and what distance will be covered, etc.
I do not need turn-by-turn instructions for navigating each city. I do want to know how long it takes to get a helicopter to get you on your way.

An important counter-question is whether the dictator anticipated the need to travel most anywhere, quickly, on short notice.

I'm not seeing any worldbuilding aspect to this at all - this is something that can be answered by looking up real-world travel methods.

Given your restrictions, helicopter to the airfield, Airforce One with in-flight refueling, Helicopter from the second airfield. This is pretty straightforward math and @KerrAvon2055 is right, this isn't worldbuilding. It's a request for research help to tell your story.

The most realistic answer, unfortunately, is that the dictator of the world doesn't need to go places on short notice. Visits by heads of state fall into two categories, sometimes overlapping: media puffery that's of symbolic, but not practical importance (and can be scheduled in advance), and deep discussion with other heads of state (which must be scheduled in advance; they're busy people too, after all).

It is quite OK for an untrained civilian to travel as a passenger in a fighter jet; Clancy's Jack Ryan did this on at least 1 occasion. Only unusual thing, it would be a two-seat fighter jet, which is not the normal entourage of a presidential aircraft.

Elon Musk's ships could probably do it in about an hour, plus travel time to Texas for launch. If he's the supreme dictator and anticipates the need to be anywhere, then he might just keep one on the pad in standby. All this other stuff is just silly, we don't even have a flightworthy SR71 left nowdays.

the most important person on earth probably shouldn't board an experimental rocket which has an extremely high probability of exploding....

You rent a helicopter to the top of the building you are talking. While the helicopter is coming, you are going to the top and the closest fighter plane with a dual seat is coming to the nearest airport. Nicaraguan air force has no supersonic fighters, so you go with their top utility plane to Mexico. While on road, USA is sending air force one to you and you will travel with air force one. Probably some risky and really hardcore f-16 would be also possible, but note: their range is only 1-2000km, far not enough for the oceans, not even with refueling.

@KerrAvon2055 I've given it some consideration, and you're right. Someone said, in a now-deleted comment, I was just being lazy and asking folks to do my research for me. Truth: that was accurate. However, I don't think every question like this would necessarily not be world-building. Mine doesn't count because the criteria collectively disallow all creativity. A less locked-down version of this could qualify, if there are sufficient degrees of freedom. In my defense, it wasn't exactly deliberate. I whittled a broader question down in a self-defeating way.

@Tom Thanks for that completely transparent, self-reflective and honest feedback! I genuinely admire that :)

My first instinct here was off topic too, but the sheer number of options and considerations make this one on topic.

Okay - I am going to take a few liberties here in places - but everything I write uses current tech.
Stage 1: Just behind the podium is a Presidential vehicle. We have a recent real-world example with the Trump Assassination attempt whereby a Politician type person was ushered to a vehicle on foot. The trip took about 1-2 minutes
Stage 2: Vehicle drives into something like a V22 Osprey to extract to the nearest airport. The V22 will be something like 5 minutes away from where the Car is.
Stage 3: The V22 lands at Augusto C. Sandino International Airport - which is about 10 miles out of the city centre - so 2 minutes.
Note
All these Vehicles would be on standby, in theatre as part of the Presidents usual motorcade/security detail.
Stage 4: Now, this is where it gets interesting.
First option: If we want RAW SPEED - then the obvious choice is an SR71 Blackbird - it has 2 seats - and it has serious cool points. It is not a High-G aircraft, and whilst it does require specialist suits, this is more due to altitude.
However, you noted in your question that you want to factor in the time for the vehicles to get there - and the idea of something like an SR71 being on standby here is not realistic.
But, I like the SR-71 and it has serious rule-of-cool points, So I am including it in my Answer.
The more realistic option - a heavily modified Concorde type aircraft that is the equivalent of the US Air Force One
Let us make the assumption that our global dictator is a busy bee - and often has many pressing engagements globally and so would want to minimize down-time in getting from Point A to Point B.
Having a supersonic Luxury airliner (which Concorde was) - is entirely reasonable. In terms of Modifications - things like Air-to-air refuelling capability (like Air Force One) - Conference facilities etc.
Edit: Concorde was used to transport the Royal Family and British Prime Minister on occasion, although this was a stock Concorde - there is precedent for it being used in an official capacity.
This aircraft would be kept on warm-standby in case the President would need a hot extraction - the V22 would land close, extract the President onto it (so lets add 5 minutes of faff here)
That is an 8.5 hour flight at Mach 2, let's add some time for ascent, descent etc. and call it a 9 hour flight - This would need 3 inflight refuels. So how would we do this?
Well, Lets assume that there would be a Carrier of some description lurking in the pacific - this would do the initial refuel at the 3 hour mark, then the rest would be able to daisy chain from US bases (in a similar method that Operation Black Buck for the Vulcan raids on Argentina did) - These tankers have 6 hours to get into position, which I think is reasonable.
Land in Jakarta - which during the 9 hours would have time to get the local motorcade resources on station - and then it would be another 15 or so minutes to get to the location.
So - all up - a 10 hour trip would be possible.
Option number 3
There is another Aircraft, that was designed in the 1950s to fly at high speeds for a long time - the XB-70 Valkyrie. It was designed to cruise at Mach 3. It was cancelled after an accident during testing... However... The technology to make it exists, the Aircraft existed - and if our President is a bit of an Aviation fan and as above - Speed is of the essence, they might have taken this aircraft, modified it (it was a Bomber, so had the space and capacity to be converted) to be their personal transport - we can do the same as above with Concorde, only instead of going at Mach 2, we can hit Mach 3 - and so our 9 hour flight becomes a 6 hour flight. Same logistics, as above (although the Daisy-chaining of refuelling probes might get a bit trickier....)
Although now that I write that - I remember that there is a Tanker variant of the Super-Hornet (which is a supersonic Jet fighter) - so we could do some fancy logistics to get them into position using the higher speed - although they would have to slow-down to refuel (data indicates that Fighters are refueling at around 300-330 knots - or about 600 kph) I would imagine that supersonic refuelling would not be ideal.
Both option 2 and Option 3 are predicated on this aircraft being the primary mode of travel and I don't think this is an unreasonable assumption - The Concorde option being more likely IMO - but the Valkyrie is a really cool aircraft - so I am including it.
To conclude
Using real aircraft and reasonable assumptions - a President could be touched down within 12 hours. Using a little bit of liberty, it could be within 8 hours.

to be fair an blackbird only needs ot be on standy within a thousand miles of you to still make it the fastest option, since it can fly to you.

The Blackbird needs JP-7, which makes it iffy to provide tankers on short notice. And tankers are subsonic, so a Concorde would have to slow down to refuel. From Navy tankers, it would have to be a relay of little ones, a couple thousand pounds at a time. This may still be faster than a more normal aircraft, or not. Could be close.

@o.m. I did add a bit about having to slow down for refueling - but given it's just 3 times and we are still going at like .9 Mach - I just handwaived.

45 minutes for a suborbital Falcon 9 + Dragon is probably an even faster option.

+1 but a slight confusion caused by the first enumerated option being "3" and feeling like "2" after the "more realistic" subheading

"and whilst it does require specialist suits, this is more due to altitude" - Wouldn't that pose a timing problem if the ordinary flight suit doesn't fit the glorious leader because of his, er, constitution? A fully pressurised cockpit may fare better

@AhmedTawfik the issue is that it presumes a Falcon 9 is assembled, prepped and ready for launch. That IMO is an unreasonable assumption. Whereas a world leader using a modified passenger plane...

@TheDemonLord, a Concorde gulps 31,600 gallons in a bit under 4 hours, while a Super Hornet would deliver perhaps 1/10th of that. So ten carrier aircraft to refuel, one after another. By that time, the tanks might be dry again. Better delay the takeoff just a little to get air force tankers ready. Oh, and would this "VIP Concorde" be fitted with Navy-style refueling nozzles?

@Cheetah That's a simple matter of tailoring. An off-the-shelf suit might not fit His Excellency's generousness, but having one custom-fitted and made before taking office would not be difficult.

There is no competitor to rocketry

Podium to exit the building, 2 mins; this will be existing SOP for the event
Building exit to designated evacuation vehicle, either armoured limousine similar to The Beast or (more likely) helicopter: 3 mins; again pre-planned, helicopter will be on hot standby as SOP and will be able to launch immediately
Travel from venue to Augusto C. Sandino International Airport: <10mins by helicopter, maybe 20 mins by road.

Thus far we have merely followed the existing doctrine and pre-prepared evacuation procedures.  This would probably be triggered instinctively to get the World Dictator moving somewhere while they work out the next steps.
No self-respecting World Dictator would travel internationally without a fighter escort, either brought from their home country or arranged with the local militaries.  If brought from home, this might be F-35s which would need to be maintained from a carrier in the western Caribbean, several would be either actively flying or on hot standby.  Nicaragua doesn't have any fighter aircraft of its own, but locally-sourced options would be MiG-29 from Cuba or F-5E from Mexico. Whichever option was in play, a fighter aircraft could reach MGA, land and turnaround comfortably within the time it took to get the WD ready to join them.

Suit up, equip and brief the WD: 25 mins to takeoff.

The WD is now in a supersonic military aircraft (better hope that the WD is an experienced pilot; if you don't want that, make it an F-16D twin-seat), within 1hr of leaving the podium.  Where do we go now?

Flight at ~Mach 1 to Cape Canaveral, Florida: 80 mins including takeoff/landing.  This is ~1,900km, so Mach 1.0 is a balance of range and speed, as you want to avoid the need for re-fueling, which should be achievable on the non-combat range of an F-35 of F-16; not so with MiG-29.

Desuit WD from fighter jumpsuit, resuit into 'Starman' suit, equip and brief the WD, travel to pad: 45 mins


Here we must apply the divine hand of the Author: by fortunate coincidence today was a designated launch day for a Dragon 2 crewed launch to the ISS, including a space tourist whose trip of a lifetime has just been unceremoniously bumped by the WD.  However fanatical your Loyal Followers are, a Falcon 9 launch is not something you can put together in three hours, it must have been intended to happen today anyway; but they are happening every couple of months so it's not wildly implausible. Since orbital rendevous with the ISS is no longer required, the launch could be delayed to meet the WD's timings if it was scheduled from any time after he left the podium. If the Falcon 9 has enough fuel to reach orbit, it certainly has enough fuel to not reach orbit, but instead deliver a ballistic trajectory with splashdown in the sea just off the coast of Jakarta. The flight engineers have had two hours to recode the launch parameters and re-brief the pilot; what could possibly go wrong?

Sub-orbital ballistic trajectory: <45 mins.

3h30m after leaving the podium, the WD is now bobbing up and down in the sea off the coast of Jarkarta. This is adequate time to scramble local search-and-rescue assets to conduct the recovery.  Exactly how long recovery to land takes will depend on how far offshore the capsule is targeted to splash down; if we assume a bum-clenchingly near 5km and a pickup in a AS565 from the Indonesian Navy, this might be as little as 5 mins flight time, plus 25 mins for the recovery itself. It's not inconceivable to have the WD in the air over Jakarta in a military helicopter, 4h after leaving the podium in Nicaragua.

The fortunate coincidence though is the major stumbling block. In the best year there were sixty launches in a year - that is a one in six chance, or fifteen percent - not good odds. And that is picking the best year. Furthermore, that is very season dependent. If it is summer - then I would probably say it is more likely - but in Winter time or outside of Rocket Launching season...

Fortunate coincidence is fair game when deus ex machina is possible. I continue to be surprised how everybody hand-waves the physical strain of going to orbit, though. For example, I doubt that most U.S. Senators would be likely to survive an emergency trip to the ISS. Donald Pleasance in Escape from New York might not survive it.

@Tom Blue Origin has sent up literal octogenarians in some of their tourism flights, this wouldn't be that much higher or faster. Actually launching into orbit would be serious overkill, you'd use a suborbital trajectory like a ballistic missile does.

Fly the Foxhound
The MiG-31 Foxhound is a Mach 3.2+ supersonic jet that may exactly fit your needs.
First of all, it falls squarely with the "current-day" requirement - it's a production aircraft with over 500 built and which is in active service with a recent midlife refit program, unlike the retired SR-71.
Some of the world leaders IRL do fly with fighter jets in tow on occasion; Vladimir Putin did visit the UAE with four Su-35s in escort in Dec 2023. Since you are the Earth's dictator, it's reasonable to assume that you always fly with one or two jet escorts and that one of them may as well be a Foxhound.
Even if you don't; while IRL, most MiG-31s are located in Russia and other CSTO countries, but under a world-wide dictatorship, it is reasonable to assume that they could be stationed all over the world as part of the United Earth Air Force, including a few in Central America.
The BM version of the Foxhound is equipped with a refueling probe and has set a sustained flight record of 7 hours in air and covering over 8,000 km with refuels. It's no-refuel flight range is known to be 5,400 km with 4 AAMs and two drop tanks; this should be bigger without armament. This still falls quite short of the 18491 km distance between Managua and Jakarta, most of which is over the Pacific. However, assuming that the former United States' Pacific infrastructure is still intact under the world government, you probably can make do with a number of in-air refuels; more on exact route later. (Of course, you have to either make CSTO and NATO refueling systems interoperable or have a fleet of Il-78's ready; I assume one of this had been covered under the worldwide dictatorship.)
Most importantly, the Foxhound is a native kerosene-fueled two-seater with air-tight cockpits. This means that in an absolute emergency, you can ride shotgun at stratospheric altitudes while dressed in a business suit. This cuts down on a big chunk of time trying to find a fitting flight suit for your possibly sizeable persona. (Don't expect to survive combat maneuvers or ejection, of course; but you can fly like that in a straight line.)
You can also pick up ordinary, passenger-jet-grade fuel; this will induce extra wear on the engines, but they shall hold.
The Actual Route
Now, assuming the original constraints, you are limited to Mach 3.2 and 5,800-ish km per hop, but the suitable modern-day aircraft can be reasonably provided on a very short notice (assuming worldwide dictatorship).
Now you need to cover the Pacific. This will mostly be done with in-air refueling with air tankers; timing refueling is very hard because it's strongly dependent on the pilot's skill and independent variables such as wind (which buffets the planes and the drogue around, making it hard to snatch it).
In-air refueling is, obviously, subsonic; but you're still moving in the right direction and you don't need to spend precious time landing, taxiing and taking off again. I'll be assuming an extra of 10-15 minutes (depending on the amount of fuel required) to account for the lost speed as opposed to high-supersonic flight.
Your first hop is probably Managua-Guadalajara, Mexico. This is 2,077 km, which is doable in a MiG-31 with a clean wing (no drop tanks and no missiles/empty gun). This is 33 minutes, and you do need to take off and land to grab your drop tanks in Guadalajara, so let's make it 50 (including landing, taxiing, refitting, fueling, and takeoff with everything at the ready).
Next hop is Guadalajara-Honolulu with drop tanks; that's 5,626 km. The MiG-31 can cover 5,400 km with four AAMs and 2 drop tanks, so we assume that's coverable without armament. Your speed is reduced to Mach 2.7 with the drop tanks and because of the engine wear, so you'll take 102 minutes to cover the distance. Factor in in-air refueling (which is obviously subsonic) over Honolulu and make it 120, or 2 hours.
Now to Samoa, which is 4,212 km or 78 minutes. Throw in refueling and make it 90. After that, it's a rather straightforward flight to Port Moresby (4,455 km which is 83 minutes, 95 with refueling) and the same distance to Jakarta.
All in all, this makes for 7.5 hours in a modern-day aircraft (and which is doable by a single pilot at the stick, because your dictator can't pilot).

This seems to me a very realistic approach, but I have 2 questions. A) this assumes the drop-tanks can be re-fueled in-air. And B) Is the time added for dropping to tanker-speed, filling up (including the extra tanks) and getting back up to Mach 2.7 again realistic?

@Tonny A) I think this can be handwaved even in hard sci-fi, because it's perfectly doable and nobody knows whether or not such system is in place on the Foxhound unless they piloted one, for it has numerous modifications. Anyway, we're already assuming CSTO-NATO compatibility refits under the worldwide regime, so, extra underwing plumbing is perfectly reasonable. B) Refueling itself takes on average 8-10 minutes for the Stratotanker and 7-8 minutes for the Midas. Energetic aerobraking time is negligible (under 30s) and 2x152 kN engines should bring you back to speed in 3-4 minutes tops.

That is assuming your precious passenger can handle the G forces braking and accelerating without a pressure suit. I'm sure he wouldn't like it much being subjected to more than 2 G. That may add some additional time for braking/accelerating. Going a bit gentle on the acceleration (in stead of full after-burner) is probably better for the overall fuel economy as well.

I think that even with the extra safety, that's 30 minutes at the very worst. Anything supersonic has the same constraints (but is considerably worse, the Raptor peaks out below Mach 2), and anything subsonic is by definition slower by a factor of 3 or more.

I agree. About 25-30 minutes extra. Call it 8 hours total. Not too shabby.

Now I think about this some more... Flying East in stead of West would probably be a little bit faster due to favorable jetstreams. So to Puerto Rico or Cuba for the first lap to get drop-tanks added then, air-refuels all the way to Indonesia.

How do you access the closest Mig-31? They are in Russia, until they arrive, you lose a lot of hours (and, being a fighter plane, probably you can not just land it and refly).

@GraySheep He already explained that in the answer. As world dictator he wil have access to ALL the military in the world, so MIG-31's can be available. Figther escorts to Airforce One/standby at nearest airport already pretty much operational standard today for Biden (or Putin). And last but not least. A Mig-31 can use regular jet-fuel available at any major air-port and is perfectly fine with a regular civilian air-field that can handle a Boeing or Airbus passenger plane.

@Tonny Yes, but the Mig31-s are in Russia. Other side of the Earth. To be used, they need to come to Managua. Or, alternatively, they can start to fly to a meeting point while the dictator is flying with a slower thing. But if you fly a Mig-31, probably you can not just take off with again, at least not without big risks.

@Tonny Beside that, the Mig31 operational range is only 720km, what means it might travel 1500km if it does not need to come back to its original airport. Increasing the speed decreases the range (going faster with 10% increases fuel consumption by more than 10%). Travel to the opposite side of the Earth takes about 20000km. I imagine many travels with various aircrafts where changeover happens on the airport, directly from plane into plane. As I google now, probably no fighter aircraft can travel over the Oceans, not even with air refueling.

Is Mach 2.7 its with-drop tanks cruising speed, or is that full-afterburner war emergency power?

The solution proposed by Eugen Sänger and Irene Bredt in 1941 was the Silbervogel rocket bomber. The aircraft was to have begun its mission propelled along a 3 km (2 mi) long rail track by a large rocket-powered sled to about 1,930 km/h (1,200 mph). The sled also pushed the nose of the aircraft up when it was up to speed for the aircraft to take off (a bit like Fireball XL5). Once airborne, it was to fire its own rocket engine and continue to climb to an altitude of 145 km (90 mi), at which point it would be travelling at about 21,800 km/h. It would then travel by 'skipping off the atmosphere' - it would lose height, enter the atmosphere where the flat bottom would generate lift, and send it up again.
The original proposal was to carry a 4000 Kg bomb from Germany to drop on the US, and then fly on to land in Japan. However, the original proposal contained a computing error which means the re-entry would have generated more heat, and probably destroyed it. But it should be possible to make an atmosphere skipping aircraft get to anywhere in the world in about 90 minutes.
This does not mean you can go from random A to B. The take-off at A would need a large and very specialised track. Something more like the X-20 Dyna-Soar (1966) took off vertically using a booster rocket.

What about some type of manned space craft designed to go into orbit and then deorbit?
Couldn't the world dictator always travel with some of them, and couldn't they have hundreds or thousands of different suborbital fights programmed into their flight computers.  So Caracas to Jakarta is selected and the rocket lifts off.
Landing in the sea or on land near Jakarta may be the tricky part.
So I guess possibly half an hour to an hour to get to the nearest space port to Caracas and then maybe a couple of hours flight time, and then half an hour to an hour from the landing site to Jakarta.  And so three to four hours at a rough guess.

Good but not available yet, at least not on a reasonably short notice. OP specifically calls for "current day", not just "modern" tech.

No world leader currently travels around with a functional space vehicle in tow, nor do I think any leader ever has. I'll meet you half-way and suppose there's a launchpad and craft within a few hundred miles, but real-world space tech can't do impromptu launches, so, nine times out of ten, waiting for the next prepped launch takes more time than commercial civilian flight would.

Who says you can't do an impromptu rocket launch? Strategic nuclear missiles can, otherwise they would be useless. Civilian space agencies don't do launch-on-demand because it's expensive, not because they can't. But what's expense to the dictator of the world?

Frame Challenge: The Need is Negated by the Setting
Using 2024 technology, a world leader can fulfil all of their obligations from anywhere in the world. No matter what your emergency is, modern leaders lead by thier words, not by thier physical presence; so, the big rush is actually to respond to the event much more so than to actually get there quickly. As other answers indicated, it will likely take no more than 15-30 minutes to get to your Mobile Command and Control Aircraft, and once there you are flying in a mobile media and conferencing center. As you travel back you will already be getting briefed on the emergency and if necessary, you will call other world leaders and make necessary arrangements long before you actually reach Jakarta, Indonesia.
While this happens, your propaganda... I mean "public relations" team will quickly knock out an appropriate response to the event and send it to you while you are still en route.  It is probable that you will already be broadcasting your response to the world before you even leave central american airspace.
While you may be making every reasonable attempt to get back in a "timely fashion", it is far more important that you take the Mobile Command and Control Aircraft than it is to take a faster means of transportation because even if it is faster, you can not actually lead from the seat of an F16 which means it actually creates a longer latency in your leadership to take one.
We can use Air Force One as the most likely real world equivalent,
Since you are going so far, you will not want to push your aircraft more than its basic cruising speed of about 580mph (930kph).  At a total distance of 18,427 km, AF1 needs just 1 aerial refueling which it can get from Hawaii making your total flight time about 20 hours.  But, because you took the slower plane, you were able to do all of your time critical leadership stuff within the 1st hour of that flight making it effectively the fastest way to respond to the emergency.

Excellent answer! People often forget just how much modern technology simplifies leadership from a distance.

With a gravity train, a person can reach any point on Earth within 42 minutes. Of course, one doesn't currently exist and it would take lots of time and money to build one, but it is definitely the fastest option to get to the opposite side of Earth. A far more practical Gravity Train that only passed through Earth's Crust would still only take 6 hours.

I'm afraid this doesn't fit the OP's constraint of "real-world current-day Earth".

I think a gravity train could not function at all if it only "passed through the Earth's crust." Gravity won't cause a vehicle to accelerate laterally, against gravity, for most of the journey, but that's what a "crust-only gravity train" would need to do: travel down 40 km, then drill horizontally through the crust in a semi-circle halfway around the planet, then back up 40 km.
